# Flex - how to trigger a black screen

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am new to flex programming. I am working at a small project which interacts with a FLEX app and I need to make a simple change to the FLEX app.

Right now it is coded to show a popup when something goes wrong informing the user (the server tells the FLEX app that something went wrong and a popup shows now). What I want is to make the entire screen go black so that the user cannot continue doing anything when the previous code (when the code that determines that something went wrong in the app) is triggered and stay that way no matter what happens next or what the user clicks or does. I would need this without requiring to use any external libs. I am using FLEX 4.6 SDK.

Like I said I am new to this, I only worked with PHP before and I need some guiding or some example or some help. Anything is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Make the mouseaction to false like mousechildren,mouseenabled etc..try it. hope it will help

Comment: Any idea how can I make the entire screen to be black? If I can do that, then the user can blindly click on anything without the black color going away.

Comment: Create a mxml with black back ground in your project. When the error will come just navigate to that mxml.

Comment: Maybe, you can try this: when the user click the OK button or close button of the popup, the app change to another "state" that is a blank color and nothing in it.